# Input decoravel para determinada funcao

Tags: html, html5

Eu sempre tive essa duvida, entretanto agora necessito disso. Existe algum script free ou algum site, ou simplesmente um nome desses BOX onde podemos moldar a mensagem com negrito, links, citacoes codes etc? como esse aqui que estou usando pra digitar..

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existem editores de texto gratuitos para utilizar em seus projetos.

Um deles é o [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), um editor de texto open source e gratuito. Dê uma olhada na documentação e veja se atende às suas necessidades.